# Colocar exceções no proxy por batch

Tags: batch, proxy

```
@echo off

REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyEnable /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyServer /t REG_SZ /d 172.16.7.200:3128 /f
pause
```

Estou usando esse comando para ativar o proxy em algumas maquinas minhas, só que ele não configura as exceções sendo assim não deixa de ter um trabalho manual!

Gostaria de adicionar algum comando para colocar as exceções!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As exceções ficam no item `ProxyOverride` que é um `REG_SZ` contendo uma lista de domínios separados por ponto e vírgula (;).

Você pode adicionar assim:

```
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyOverride /t REG_SZ /d "google.com;yahoo.com;bing.com" /f
```

Comment: vlw man obrigado !