# Como programar uma hora para desligar o computador automaticamente com um ficheiro Batch

Tags: batch, cmd

Eu estou a seguir um tutorial do site [Super User](https://superuser.com/a/215566/432296) da rede de sites Stack Exchange, com a ideia de programar o meu computador para se auto-desligar passando `X` tempo, após termos corrido ou seja feito duplo clique num ficheiro `.bat`, em vez de utilizar um programa aleatório para fazer isso.

Como é explicado na resposta, primeiro temos que [criar um ficheiro Batch](http://www.wikihow.com/Write-a-Batch-File) (`.bat`) e dentro dele adicionar o código abaixo, logo após o `@echo off`:

```
shutdown -s -t 1800
```

que irá desligar o computador passando 30 minutos (1800 segundos) após termos corrido o ficheiro.
Para cancelar esta ação, basta trocarmos o código acima pelo código abaixo (ou criar um novo ficheiro) e corrê-lo com o seguinte código:

```
shutdown -a
```

Então eu criei um ficheiro Batch e dentro dele adicionei a seguinte linha de código:

```
@ECHO OFF shutdown -s -t 1800
```

Mas quando eu corro o ficheiro, nada acontece. Será que estou a fazer algo de errado?

Comment: Como assim a pergunta está foro do escopo? A pergunta é sobre programação e até inclusive existem tags próprias relacionadas com a pergunta e outras perguntas feitas sobre o mesmo tópico (`.bat/batch`) como por exemplo: [1](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/76280), [2](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/48057), [3](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/49418) e por aí [em diante](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch?page=2&sort=newest&pagesize=15). Talvez possa ser um tópico menos falado e que o pessoal não está acostumado a ver, mas eu não acho que esteja fora do escopo.

Comment: entendi teu ponto de vista, mas note que no caso das perguntas que citou, (no meu ponto de vista) apenas [esta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/76280/como-criar-um-arquivo-de-configuração-bat-no-windows) dentro do escopo, as demais não. Não quer dizer que porque tem perguntas abertas que seja dentro do escopo, é que geralmente elas passam "batido" :) - Fui eu quem votou por fechar, mas mesmo assim tentei lhe fornecer uma resposta, no entanto olhando bem, a sua pergunta realmente parece dentro do escopo, pois fala do .bat e não dos comando usados, voto de fechar retirado e +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faltou uma quebra de linha

```
@ECHO OFF
shutdown -s -t 1800
```

Note que tudo que vem depois de um comando especifico (o `ECHO` por exemplo) não é executado é considerado parâmetro dele, então a quebra de linha se faz necessária.

As únicas maneiras de executar 2 comandos ou mais na mesma linha é usar `&` ou `|` por exemplo (não tenho muito conhecimento de batch).

Pra "depurar" o resultado da execução você pode usar o `pause` assim:

```
@ECHO OFF
shutdown -s -t 1800
pause
```

Desta maneira o .bat não irá fechar sozinho.

Comment: Obrigado Guilherme, agora funcionou certinho! :)